# What to do if my target variable is column of lists?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-extraction, preprocessing, tranformation

How I can transform my target variable(**Y**)?

As it is list, I cann`t use it for fitting model, because I must use integers for fitting.

Comment: Please provide some more information. Y is a list of what - list of numbers, strings or something else? It would be better if you give 2-3 examples and also tell what kind of analysis you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have multiple Y. Each item will be a binary variable which means that item exists or not.

Comment: off course in the case order of items it's not important

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are trying to ask then below line would help you.

```
import numpy as np
target=np.array(y)
```

If you need something else,please specify in detail.